# Call to undefined function update_sub_field() ACF

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update a subfield using this function update_sub_field(), but the page returns me the this

Fatal error: Call to undefined function update_sub_field() in /directory...

update_sub_field(array('onda', 2, 'votos'), $novoValor, $post_id );

Why!? :s The plugin ACF is installed and working great.

Comment: From where are you calling the function?

Comment: @rnevius What do you mean? Inside or outside the loop? Its outside :/

Answer (score 1):

Guess I found out...

This function is only available for ACF PRO (ACF 5.0) which will be released still this year (2014) for free.

My version is 4.3.8